# Monorepos, images are not being loaded at differnt base path

Tags: reactjs, next.js, vercel

### Environment

I'm working with two frontend projects under the same `GitHub` repository. Following the guide provided by Vercel about [monorepos](https://vercel.com/blog/monorepos) and taking as an example Vercel's [with-zone example](https://github.com/vercel/next.js/tree/canary/examples/with-zones), I've structured my project in the same way as in the example.

with-zones/

--platform //This is the main project (know as home in Vercel's guide)

--tools

Both deploys work fine, this means that I can access **platform.vercel.com** and **platform.vercel.com/tools** (these URLs are only examples)

### **The problem**

Images are not loading when the URL is different from platform.vercel.app/tools (/tools is the basePath of the second project. No errors are logged in the terminal/browser so I'm stuck at this point. I just see the alt tag in the window.

In short, for the following urls:

- platform.vercel.app/tools -> Images are loaded successfully
- platform.vercel.app/tools/page1 -> Images are **not** loaded

#### Note.

I'm not having this issue with the main project, platform. I'm using **.jpg** images

#### Code

tools/next.config.js

```
module.exports = {
  basePath: '/tools', 
    webpack: (config, options) => {
      config.module.rules.push({
          test: /\.csv$/,
          loader: 'csv-loader',
          options: {
            dynamicTyping: true,
            header: true,
            skipEmptyLines: true,
          }
        })
  
      return config
    },

  }
```

Img tag at any page

```
<img 
    src='categories/fluids.svg' // categories is in public folder
    className={sizes.imgSmall}
/>
```

tools/package.json

```
{
...
  "dependencies": {
    "next": "10.1.3",
    "react": "17.0.2",
..
```

Thank you in advance for your time and answers!

Comment: What Next.js version are you using?

Comment: Next version: 10.1.3

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if this is the best way to solve this problem (probably not), but including the **basePath** ( */tools* in this case) in the `src` of any image tag solves the problem.

```
<img 
    src='/tools/categories/fluids.svg'
    className={sizes.imgSmall}
    alt='Fluid mechanics icono' />
```

It works for any page in the tools project's page folder.